# Running a for loop inside a function called in react's render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Hey guys i have and object that contains key as the states and its value as array of cities for which i wanna loop over in render method and show the data

For example my object is like

```
{
A:{cities:[0,1,2,3]},
B:{cities:[0,1,2,3]}
}
```

so in render method i called

```
render(){
{this.renderAllStates()}
}
```

and then

```
renderAllStates = () => {
    console.log(data);
    // let parsedData=JSON.parse(states)
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
      console.log(key, value.cities);
     return <Collapsible trigger={key}>
        <p>
          This is the collapsible content. It can be any element or React
          component you like.
        </p>
        <p>
          It can even be another Collapsible component. Check out the next
          section!
        </p>
      </Collapsible>;
    }
  };
```

so this renders only the first state inside my component, cause i am using

> return

but then if i do not use return it says

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
> no-unused-expressions

so my question is where should i use the return method keyword here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to render multiple items, you have to return an array or a React fragment. In this case, an array makes sense:

```
renderAllStates = () => {
    return Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) =>
        <Collapsible key={key} trigger={key}>
            <p>
                This is the collapsible content. It can be any element or React
                component you like.
            </p>
            <p>
                It can even be another Collapsible component. Check out the next
                section!
            </p>
        </Collapsible>
    );
};
```

Note I added a `key` property, since these are entries in an array. React needs the key to track things when the array changes.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the elements, you need to store them in an array and return.
Better use .map function in the following way.

```
renderAllStates = () => (
  Object.keys(data).map((key) => (
     <Collapsible trigger={key}>
      <p>
        This is the collapsible content. It can be any element or React
        component you like.
      </p>
      <p>
        It can even be another Collapsible component. Check out the next
        section!
      </p>
    </Collapsible>
 ))
)
```

For value, use data[key].

I hope it works for you.